# R - Substring of column value

Tags: r, dataframe, substring

I'd like to store a substring value from the "Date" column into another variable.
This is what my data frame looks like:

[image: Example]

My data frame is called "test".
What I want to achieve is to take the last two numbers of the Date values and store them into another data frame. So the end result would look like this:

```
   Value
1  01
2  01
3  01
```

This is what I've done already:

```
t.sub<-substring(test$Data, 5,6)
```

However, R returned this:

```
character(0)
```

and:

```
t.sub<-data.frame(substring(test$Data,5,6))
```

R returned this:

```
[1] substr(molten$Data, 5, 6)
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: can you dput your data.frame `test`?

Comment: You could convert the `Date` variable into a proper date format and use R's functions to extract whatever part of the said date. Is the width of the `Date` variable fixed, or  can it change?

Comment: `substring("201102", 5,6)` works fine for me. And instead of providing pictures, you should provide your actual data, unless you know a way of converting pictures to data in R.

Comment: The reason you were receiving empty string is because you were using `test$Data` instead of `test$Date`. I.e., you made a typographical error. Try  `substring(test$Date,5,6)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, wow.. I can't even believe it myself.... Sorry guys! The code worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `gsub`, first make sure to convert your date to character:

```
gsub('.*([0-9]{2})$', '\\1',as.character(test$Data))
```

Comment: The desired output would be "01". Your code returns "1" only. Is there a possibility to do so?

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thanks!

Comment: Hows that different from `substring("201102", 5, 6)`? I also don't think you need `as.character` here at all.

Comment: That's why I asked for dput!

Comment: You just very overcomplicated this. OP just had typographical error and wrote `Data` instead of `Date`. Also, `gsub` works with `factors` too. Try `gsub('.*([0-9]{2})$', '\\1',factor("201102"))`. Finally, you can just use `sub` here.

Comment: Have a (+1) for not loading unnessacery packages and nice regex skills though.

Answer (score 2):

For string related questions I would highly recommend using the package stringr. And here's my solution.

```
require(stringr)
Date <- as.character(201101)
Date <- str_sub(Date, start=5L, end=6L)
```

You could replace the Date using your data frame such as df$Date.